# How to transfer a few text messages from one phone to another

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, sms, data-transfer, mms, samsung-galaxy-s7

I had a Samsung Galaxy S3 which I used for some time.  After getting a Galaxy S7, I transferred all my text messages and other stuff to the new phone using Smart Switch.  However, last week I had to use the old phone again, and now I am wondering if there are any easy way to transfer the messages I send/received during that week to my new phone?  Possibly, if there is a way of transferring the messages one at a time (by Bluetooth or something) this would also be helpful, as it is not a large amount messages.

I tried to do it with Smart Switch, hoping it could somehow merge the messages from the two phones, but it would not sync messages.  Maybe because the new phone already had a lot.

Searching the internet I seemed only to find solutions for transferring everything from one phone to a new phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SMS backup and restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore) has

> Option to select which text conversations to backup or restore

Though it is manual and not by date . This should be fine in your case as you don't have too many

[image]

On the next screen you can select the messages manually and create a backup

Thanks to a acejavelin who [pointed out](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/178050/how-to-transfer-a-few-text-messages-from-one-phone-to-another/178051#comment228665_178051) that restoration can be done for a specific date range. Acejavelin further adds

> The restore process does a cleanup to remove duplicate messages

Comment: +1... Beat me to it by 2 minutes, I was literally typing a similar answer when this was posted. SMS Backup & Restore is excellent for this, and all SMS/MMS backup and restore operations, even scheduled backups to the clould.

Comment: I was going to add that although  you can't select specific messages or date ranges when backing up (the original question was about a weeks long time frame), you can select a specific date range (such as the last 14 days) when restoring them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @beeshyams and thanks acejavelin for the date range comment.  This seems to be a great way of doing it.  Do any of you know what happens if a accidentally restore a message I already got.  Will I get two copies, or will I just get one?

Comment: @Kristian The restore process does a cleanup to remove duplicate messages... I have never had an issue with this and I have done it more times than I like to count.

Comment: It worked like a charm.  Thanks a bunch.  That really helped, and I must say SMS backup and restore really seems like a nice App.