# How can I selectively delete hundreds of SMS conversations?

Tags: sms, delete

I work in IT and I'm part of an on-call rotation.  Normally we use a dedicated on-call phone, but that's not available since covid, so I'm using my own device right now.  We had a major networking outage tonight which resulted in roughly 600 SMS notifications from our monitoring service to my phone.

The problem is that each one of these notifications comes from a different address (I don't know why/how that works).  So rather than 600 new messages in a single conversation, I now have ~600 new conversations in my Messaging app with a single message each.  I would like to delete them so I don't have to scroll through 600 conversations to find my conversations with friends.

Is there any way to bulk delete conversations based on some kind of search filter?  I did see [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/35452/337236), but the answers only address how to delete all SMS messages.  I would only like to delete the conversations which were generated by this incident.

I'm on a OnePlus 3T with LineageOS 17.1 (based on Android 10).  My phone is rooted so I can run adb commands on it from my Linux desktop.

Comment: if you prefer doing it on Windows you can use [MyPhoneExplorer](https://www.fjsoft.at/forum/viewtopic.php?t=31155) (you can filter by keywords, select all + delete like in Thunderbird)

Answer (score 0):

*Act fast* to get quick results

- Use [SMS backup and restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore&hl=en_IN&gl=US) and backup all your SMSes to local storage on device *immediately*.
- Go to the app menu and choose restore. It will select the backup you made. Go to advanced options and select *only restore backup since* and you choose date *before* you got flooded by all these SMSes.
- Assuming you don't have any important messages *after* the chosen date , you are good. If you have, follow steps in answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/178050/131553) to backup, selected conversations and choose those to be restored. It doesn't restore duplicates and at most you may end up having to manually delete a few messages
- Alternatively, you can export the SMS backup file which is in XML format to your laptop, search for the common term in these messages, delete all those, maybe use a script to do that. Transfer the file to your device and restore to device.

Comment: You deleted your original comment which suggested using this same app to export the backups to XML, writing a script to prune the XML file, and running a restore from the modified XML backup.  I'm not sure why you deleted that comment because that's exactly what I ended up doing and it worked quite well.

Comment: It's good that your problem was solved by the earlier suggestion. I deleted that comment thinking it was probably difficult (which was a mistake). I added that suggestion to the answer, so that you can mark it as accepted. Thank you